# Pandas index match with time values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to index match 2 dataframes and write the data back to excel. The Excel file that has to be filled looks like this:

```
     Name  Location        Date  Open   High   TimeH   Low    TimeL    Close
1  Orange  New York  20200501.0   5.5   5.58   18:00   5.45   16:00     5.7
0   Apple     Minsk  20200505.0   3.5   3.85    NaN    3.45    NaN      3.65
2   Steak    Dallas  20200506.0   8.5   8.85    NaN    8.45    NaN      8.65
```

The 'TimeH' and 'TimeL' should be index'd from a dataframe that looks like this

```
    Name      Date     Time  Open  High   Low  Close  Volume  VWAP  Trades
4   Apple  20200505  15:30:00  3.50  3.85  3.45   3.70    1500  3.73      95
5   Apple  20200505  17:00:00  3.65  3.70  3.50   3.60    1600  3.65      54
6   Apple  20200505  20:00:00  3.80  3.85  3.35   3.81    1700  3.73      41
7   Apple  20200505  22:00:00  3.60  3.84  3.45   3.65    1800  3.75      62
4   Steak  20200506  10:00:00  8.50  8.85  8.45   8.70    1500  8.73      95
5   Steak  20200506  12:00:00  8.65  8.70  8.50   8.60    1600  8.65      54
6   Steak  20200506  14:00:00  8.80  8.85  8.45   8.81    1700  8.73      41
7   Steak  20200506  16:00:00  8.60  8.84  8.45   8.65    1800  8.75      62
```

And then be pasted to the excel file, which should look like this after everything has worked:

```
     Name  Location        Date  Open   High    TimeH     Low    TimeL      Close
1  Orange  New York  20200501.0   5.5   5.58   18:00:00   5.45   16:00:00    5.7
0   Apple     Minsk  20200505.0   3.5   3.85   10:00:00   3.45   20:00:00    3.65
2   Steak    Dallas  20200506.0   8.5   8.85   15:30:00   8.45   14:00:00    8.65
```

I was using the following code to index the values 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', which works great:

```
rdf13 = rdf12.groupby(['Name','Date']).agg(Open=('Open','first'),High=('High','max'),Low=('Low','min'), Close=('Close','last'),Volume=('Volume','sum'),VWAP=('VWAP','mean'),Trades=('Trades','sum')).reset_index()
result11 = pd.merge(rdf13, rdf11, how='inner', on=['Name', 'Date']).iloc[:,:-4].dropna(1).rename(columns = {"Open_x": "Open", "High_x": "High", "Low_x": "Low", "Close_x": "Close", "Volume_x": "Volume", "VWAP_x": "VWAP", "Trades_x": "Trades"})
result12 = result11.reindex(index=result11.index[::-1])
result13 = result12[['Name', 'Location', 'Date', 'Check_2','Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'VWAP', 'Trades']].reset_index()

readfile11 = pd.read_excel("Trackers\TEST Tracker.xlsx")

readfile11['Count'] = np.arange(len(readfile11))
df11 = readfile11.set_index(['Name', 'Location', 'Date'])
df12 = result13.set_index(['Name', 'Location', 'Date'])

fdf11 = df12.combine_first(df11).reset_index().reindex(readfile11.columns, axis=1).sort_values('Count')

print("Updated Day1 Data Frame")
print(fdf11)

writefdf10 = fdf11.to_excel("Trackers\TEST Tracker.xlsx", "Entries", index=False)
```

But when I append it to index the TimeH value with the following code:

```
colnames40 = rdf12.rename(columns = {"Time": "TimeH"})

result41 = pd.merge(colnames40, rdf11, how='inner', on=['Name', 'Date', 'High']).iloc[:,:-4].dropna(1).rename(columns = {"TimeH_x": "TimeH"})
result42 = result41.reindex(index=result41.index[::-1])
result43 = result42[['Name', 'Location', 'Date', 'Check_2', 'High', 'TimeH']].reset_index()

readfile41 = pd.read_excel("Trackers\TEST Tracker.xlsx")

readfile41['Count'] = np.arange(len(readfile41))
df41 = readfile41.set_index(['Name', 'Location', 'Date', 'High'])
df42 = result43.set_index(['Name', 'Location', 'Date', 'High'])

fdf41 = df42.combine_first(df41).reset_index().reindex(readfile41.columns, axis=1).sort_values('Count')

print("Updated Day3 Data Frame")
print(fdf41)

writefdf40 = fdf41.to_excel("Trackers\TEST Tracker.xlsx", "Entries", index=False)
```

it does not seem to work for some reason and returns nothing, so the 'NaN' values in the 'TimeH' column stay 'NaN'. I messed around with the variables, but I either got errors because I did something wrong or it still returned 'NaN' values to me.

Can someone here help me to make python index the time values?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I just had a little typo in my code.

```
esult41 = pd.merge(colnames40, rdf11, how='inner', on=['Name', 'Date', 'High']).iloc[:,:-4].dropna(1).rename(columns = {"TimeH_x": "TimeH"})
```

should have been

```
esult41 = pd.merge(colnames40, rdf31, how='inner', on=['Name', 'Date', 'High']).iloc[:,:-4].dropna(1).rename(columns = {"TimeH_x": "TimeH"})
```

Problem now is that the data returns duplicate values, which makes sense because of the reference `rdf31`, but the issue is that `df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=False)` returns 'None' values for some reason, but thats outside the scope of this question.